# twitter regex that discard no alpha signs

Tags: regex

I try to write a simple regex that idenitifes a twitter account:

```
https\://twitter.com\/[\w\/\.=-]*
```

My goal is to capture: 
https://twitter.com/anyusername

**but discard everything that may contain "?" or "/" like**

https://twitter.com/search?q=search

https://twitter.com/anyusername/status/etc

(My string is a TEXT that contain lot of text including the twitter address I want to capture and some I don't want to capture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an end of line anchor to make sure the regex checks the whole url:

```
https:\/\/twitter.com\/[\w.=-]*$
```

[Also, you don't need to escape `.` within a character class to mean a literal period]

I also removed escape sequences that are unnecessary but since you might be using `/` delimiters for the regex, I escaped those.

---

Since your text to match also contains other text, you might try a negative lookahead instead:

```
https:\/\/twitter.com\/(?!\S*[\/?])[\w.=-]*
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/jV1vD3)

`(?!\S*[\/?])` is the negative lookahead and will prevent a match if there's a `/` or `?` in the username part (where the username part is being defined as a sequence of non-space characters)

Comment: sorry, this does not work: my string is a TEXT that contain lot of text not only the twitter address

Comment: @user300675 Added another regex to my answer

Answer (score 0):

use this Regex pattern

```
https:\/\/twitter\.com\/(#!\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sM4bW4)</kbd>